# scala dataframe join columns and split arrays explode spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some co-ordinates in multiple array columns in a dataframe and want to split them to have the x,y,z in separate columns in order, column1 data first, then column 2

for example...

```
        COL 1                   |               COL2
[[x,y,z],[x,y,z],[x,y,z]...]    |   [[x,y,z],[x,y,z],[x,y,z]...]

e.g
    [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]...]    |   [[8,8,8],[9,9,9],[10,10,10]...]
```

required OUTPUT

```
    COL X       |       COL Y       |       COL Z
x,x,x,x,x....   |   y,y,y,y,y....   |   z,z,z,z,z....

e.g.
 1,2,3,..,8,9,10..  |   1,2,3,..,8,9,10..   |   1,2,3,..,8,9,10..
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_union` function as follows

```
df.select(
      array_union($"col1._1", $"col2._1").as("x"),
      array_union($"col1._2", $"col2._2").as("y"),
      array_union($"col1._3", $"col2._3").as("z"))
```

INPUT

```
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                        |col2                                              |
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]|[[8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11]]|
+--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

OTUPUT

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|x                         |y                         |z                         |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11]|
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:------     
Can't extract value from col1#14290: need struct type but got string;-----      

this is because the col1 and col2 are strings  - how do i convert them to structs

Comment: Those are strings? Even with the [ and ] chars? Please, can you provide an example dataframe and a way to create it?

Comment: yes it is from a csv file on a s3 bucket.... ----
spark.read
         .option("header", "true")
         .option("inferSchema", "true")
         .option("delimiter", "|")
          .csv("s3TestFile")
          .select($"col1",$"col2")